# form upload of an image, storing in database and displaying (when needed)

Tags: php, mysql

So, i have the code (for creating table in database ,using BLOB as a datatype) :

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE voter_info1 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
img BLOB NOT NULL,
vid VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password1 VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

And storing values in database like :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO voter_info1 (firstname,img,,vid,password1)
VALUES ('$firstname','$img','$vid','$password1')";
```

Is the code correct ?? (according to me it is because the storing of image takes place in database, review needed though!!)

Now, i want to display the image somewhere in the program , here is the code for that :-

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM voter_info1 WHERE vid='".$voter_id."' ";
    $result_getname = $conn->query($sql);

      while($row = $result_getname->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<img src="$mime,'.base64_encode( $row["img"] ).'" 
            width="80px" height="80px">'; 
         }
```

What i figured out is that the image is being stored in database and if i echo the image it gives its name (ex - my_image.jpg) but the image is not being displayed , rather i have a broken link of the image..
What could be the problem ?

Comment: *"review needed though"* - That would quality to move the post to code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - Since this part of the Stack network deals with problematic code, not working code.

Comment: Sometimes problems become more visible if you check the output of your application verbatim, that is view-source (or similar) in your browser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if anywhere

Answer (score 0):

To display the image in the html, with php. What is done mainly is that you have a folder where the images are stored and what you save is the file image in that folder and the path of that file as a string and save it.

For example, let's say we have website root cms and inside cms directory we have a folder called images. So, what we do is, in the form we use enctype multipart/form-data, have an input of type file (choose file...) button and save that in php as so:

```
//Save image in a variable for displaying the form.
$image = $post_image = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];

//Save image in a variable to store it in server.
$post_image_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];

//Save image to the /image file.
move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "{$post_image}");
```

And finally we can access it by using the image in from the db as (file path might change):

```
$img = $POST['image']; // /images/image.jpg
```

Now, do an echo in the src attribute in the  of $img. Now we access the file in the server.

Answer (score 0):

The image does not actually get stored in the database, Only the path to the image does, Read into uploading an image with php. Then once you have the code sorted to actually move the file to the path on the server you will have to get the file path and the image name you stored it with and send that data to the database then when you echo out the img you can use the src stored in the database

I highly recommend looking into 
https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php
It will save a massive amount of headaches if your dealing with uploading images

It has very good documentation and is very easy to use, and hasnt let me down yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to improve in this situation:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE voter_info1 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, <-- email size should be increased to 256 @ see: 
[https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?eid=1690]
img BLOB NOT NULL, <-- images should normally not be stored directly in the database, instead a filename or identifier to find it on the disk should be used and stored as a varchar
vid VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password1 VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL, <-- this looks like it might contain the password of the user in plaintext form, that is not recommended, instead an encrypted hash should be stored @ see: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php][2]
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Next the INSERT statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO voter_info1 (firstname,img,,vid,password1)
VALUES ('$firstname','$img','$vid','$password1')";
```

It should first specify all the columns that are going to be used with backticks(`) around the columns to avoid naming issues.
Also the amount of columns specified should match the amount of values specified, you have one empty column definition.
The final result would then look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `voter_info1` (`firstname`,`img`,`vid`,`password1`)
VALUES ('$firstname','$img','$vid','$password1')";
```

And finally the fetching of data:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM voter_info1 WHERE vid='".$voter_id."' ";
$result_getname = $conn->query($sql);

  while($row = $result_getname->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo '<img src="$mime,'.base64_encode( $row["img"] ).'" 
        width="80px" height="80px">'; 
     }
```

There are a couple of things here to take into consideration.
If you have the image as binary data in the database and you want to make it inline img src, you should prefix it with: src="data:image/png;base64,[binary data here, base64 encoded like you are doing]"
You are using $mime, but the code does not describe what $mime is or if it is set correctly.

Also the code does not show if you are using base64_decode while storing the binary data into the database, that should also be done.

So, in short, the most likely culprit in your code is not specifying the img src tag correctly.